# Creating a list of base class with a list of subclasses

Tags: list, scala, inheritance, types

I've two subclasses (`Child1, Child2`) of a base class (`Parent`).

I've a list (`kids`) that contains objects of subclasses. I want to create a new list (`typedKids`) of type `List[Parent]` from `kids`.

As you can see in the REPL session below I can create a list by directly adding the invidiuals elements to the list `val typedKidsWorks : List[Parent] = List(c1,c2,c3,c4)`  which works. However, `val typedKids : List[Parent] = List(kids)` doesn't. Any idea what I'm missing here?

```
scala> abstract class Parent
defined class Parent

scala> case class Child1(name:String) extends Parent
defined class Child1

scala> case class Child2(name:String) extends Parent
defined class Child2

scala> val c1 = Child1("first")
c1: Child1 = Child1(first)

scala> val c2 = Child2("second")
c2: Child2 = Child2(second)

scala> val c3 = Child1("third")
c3: Child1 = Child1(third)

scala> val c4 = Child2("fourth")
c4: Child2 = Child2(four)

scala> val kids = List(c1,c2,c3,c4)
kids: List[Product with Serializable with Parent] = List(Child1(first), Child2(second), Child1(third), Child2(four))

//how to make this work ? 
scala> val typedKids : List[Parent] = List(kids)
<console>:40: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Product with Serializable with Parent]
 required: Parent
       val typedKids : List[Parent] = List(kids)

//this works 
scala> val typeKidsWorks : List[Parent] = List(c1,c2,c3,c4)
typeKidsWorks: List[Parent] = List(Child1(first), Child2(second), Child1(third), Child2(four))


                                  ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kids` is already a `List[Parent]`. You don't need to call `List` again. You don't need to do anything but an assignment.

```
val typedKids: List[Parent] = kids
```

Alternatively (though there's no reason to do this), you could also write:

```
val typedKids: List[Parent] = List(kids:_*)
```

Answer (score 0):

The type signature for `List(kids)` is

```
List[List[Product with Serializable with Parent]]
```

The correct form would be

```
val typedKids : List[Parent] = kids
```

since `kids` is already a list of classes sub-classing `Parent`